# How to transfer data from an input field to another js file

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to vue and I have a simple component that takes in text.

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" id="chatInput" v-model="chatValue"> 
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  name: 'chat-room',
  data: function () {
    return {
      chatValue: ''
    }
  }
}
```

So far, the chatValue variable binds to the input tag. I would like to get the value of the chatValue into another js file so I can manipulate the value.Also, I was looking at the vue documentation and it seemed state management seemed to do the trick but I had a hard time understanding the concept. Can I implement state management to execute my desire? If not, how may I?

Comment: You should `$emit` the value to the parent component. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Data that is shared between components should be owned by a module that provides an interface to the data item. The most common way this is done is that a parent component owns the data and children of that parent accept the data item as a prop, emitting events when the data item should change.

That is described in the [documentation here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components).

If the components are less closely related, the data can be made more akin to a global variable by the use of an event bus, [described here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication).